# Magento 2 admin grid error

Tags: admin, grid, magento2.2.2

In Magento 2.2.2, clicking of custom admin gives the [this](https://pastebin.com/9FdHzXa6) error.

How to fix it.

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/11110

Comment: @KGR, Thank you. I Sorted the Issue. Issue is i added the space in as property: `<block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="  order_id">
                           `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Fixed the Issue. Issue is i added the space in as property:

```
<block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as=" order_id">
```

Removed space before `order_id` property.

```
<block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="order_id">
```